# Web-Scraping a una página web que requiere autenticación básica HTTP

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Estoy tratando de webscraping a un sitio web que, cuando visitó, pide credenciales como un pop-up.

Es el tipo de ventana emergente que se obtiene cuando un sitio web quiere HTTP Auth, sin embargo, en Python, no soy capaz de pasar de allí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito por lo menos darle cancelar o iniciar sesión directamente desde este.

Utilizo Selenium, web-driver chrome.

¿Alguien podria ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a un Alert que pide usuario y contraseña? Entonces mírate: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.alert.html En estas preguntas es importante que siempre que sea posible dejes un enlace a la página para facilitar las cosas.

Comment: mira subi una imagen para que tengas claro a que me refiero.

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que estemos hablando ***HTTP basic authentication*** tenemos varias opciones para llevarlo a cabo usando Selenium:

- Embeber usuario y contraseña directamente en la url, siguiendo el patrón `http://usuario:contraseña@host`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver

  user = "admin"
  password = "secret"

  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://{}:{}@www.tupagina.com".format(user,  password))
  ```
- Capturar el *Alert* y usar el método `authenticate`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  url = "http://www.tupagina.com/"
  user = "admin"
  password = "secret"

  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  driver.get(url)

  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
  alert = driver.switch_to.alert
  alert.authenticate(user, password)
  ```
- Capturar el *Alert* y usar el método `send_keys`:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  url = "http://www.tupagina.com/"
  user = "admin"
  password = "secret"

  driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get(url)

  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
  alert = driver.switch_to.alert
  alert.send_keys(user + Keys.TAB + password )
  alert.accept()
  ```

Si solo quieres cerrar el *Alert* basta con usar el método `dismiss`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.dismiss()
```

Existen más formas, como usar `requests` para generar cookies de sesión y usarlas en Selenium.

Comment: utilice el ultimo para cerrarlo y no funciono probare algun otro

Comment: Todo el código está probado con un `alert`. `authenticate` da problemas en Firefox pero el resto funcionan sin problemas. ¿Obtienes algún error?

Comment: no, no me da error simplemente no hace nada.

Comment: Diego pues es raro que se limite a no hacer nada, sin lanzar ninguna excepción. Si colocas un `print(alert)` después de `alert = driver.switch_to.alert`que obtienes en ese print? Habría que asegurarse que estamos tratando con un Alert y no con con otra cosa como un iframe... ¿Existiría la posibilidad de que compartieras la url objetivo?

Comment: No quiero hacer el link publico hay alguna manera de pasertelo directamente

Comment: Has logrado algo?  @FJSevilla

Comment: @DiegoLopez he estado un poco ocupado, pero le echado un vistazo y el problema es que estamos ante una autentificación que usa SPNEGO y no se trata de un "web" popup sino de un popup lanzado directamente por el navegador antes de que la página cargue siquiera, como driver.get queda bloqueado el resto de código  nunca se ejecuta (y por tanto no puedes enviar pulsaciones de teclas)  a no ser que cierres manualmente el popup permitiendo que cargue la página. Es posible que deshabilitando los popups bloqueantes en el navegador (de ser posible) se pueda evitar esto.¿Has intentado usar otro driver?

Comment: Logre saltearme eso haciendo que se cargue en una pestaña y abrir en una nueva el mismo link por alguna razon se saltea. En conclucion me toco abrirlo en dos pestañas para poder saltearlo. Gracias! por su ayuda.

Comment: Curioso, yo primero probé con Firefox y no podía reproducir tu problema. Pero en Chrome si ocurre lo que te comentaba, bloqueando la carga. Es cierto que se saltea ese paso, así como la comprobación de la compatibilidad con SPNEGO del navegador...

Comment: Si, aunque me alegra que pude pasar de hay directamente al formulario.

Answer (score 0):

La autenticación BASIC AUTH puede emularse enviando un header de autorización.

Si la combinación usuario/password fuera `user1` y `mipass`, es necesario calcular la cadena en base 64 de `user1:mipass` que es `dXNlcjE6bWlwYXNz`.

```js
console.log(btoa('user1:mipass'));
```

Luego, en tu request, si añades el header

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcjE6bWlwYXNz
```

Va a entrar logueado a la página que quieres scrapear

Comment: porque es necesario pasarlo a base 64 ?

Comment: Es la unica manera de conseguirlo?

Comment: Entiendo que así es como un sitio web desencripta el header cuando empieza como Basic